# XPATH XML Feed - how to grab data from classes with spaces

Tags: xpath

I am having trouble grabbing data from XML and can't figure out why. From my recking the context would be //event and then all the other attributes are one level down so I'd need .// to grab these? I cannot seem to grab even one piece of this. Also I have never dealt with the spaces in this and wondering how to do that a well, for example, grab the home id tag. The looped data is contained within 
Any help appreciated greatly.

```
<RSP api="site" request="get_events" ts="1383569509" ts_timezone="Australia/Darwin" rc="0">
 <events>
  <event external_id="2589501" id="775159">
      <name separator="vs">Sparta Rotterdam v Achilles 29</name>
      <home id="34482">Sparta Rotterdam</home>
      <away id="82037">Achilles 29</away>
      <datetime tz="GMT" tz_gmt_offset="0" unix="1383643800">2013-11-05 19:00:00</datetime>
      <status>live</status>
      <wp_ref>775159</wp_ref>
      <parent_category_id>9</parent_category_id>
      <category_id>5368</category_id>
      <parent_category_name>Soccer Matches</parent_category_name>
      <category_name>Dutch Jupiler League</category_name>
      <market_count>4</market_count>
  </event>
  <event external_id="2594137" id="774957">
      <name separator="vs">Maccabi Yavne v Hapoel Nazareth Illit</name>
      <home id="379120">Maccabi Yavne</home>
      <away id="124154">Hapoel Nazareth Illit</away>
      <datetime tz="GMT" tz_gmt_offset="0" unix="1383550200">2013-11-04 17:00:00</datetime>
      <status>live</status>
      <wp_ref>774957</wp_ref>
      <parent_category_id>9</parent_category_id>
      <category_id>7098</category_id>
      <parent_category_name>Soccer Matches</parent_category_name>
      <category_name>Israeli Liga Leumit</category_name>
      <market_count>1</market_count>
  </event>
 <events>
</RSP>
```

Comment: where are the spaces? Please show your current code

Comment: You would have to use `./*` to get all child elements, not `.//` (that's not even syntactically valid). To get to the id of `<home>` you use `./home/@id`.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm truly a novice. I got this running. For any other novices out there. I used the following: Context "//event" This will do all the info in quotation marks "./home/@id" and for the stuff between the >Data here< you will need "./name[@separator='vs']". Thanks again. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: mmm, seems I have not fully accomplished this, does anyone know how I can grab the top tags; "external_id" and "id". Can't seem to figure it out. Tried /external_id and ./external_id but can't grab the data. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Ok, it is "./@external_id". Hope I save someone hours of trial and error.. :)

Comment: Those are attributes, not tags. They need either `@` (or the long form, `attribute::`) in front of them, otherwise the XPath will be interpreted as *"child named `<external_id>`"*. You ought to read a few basics about XPath, that's much more efficient than poking around until, by accient, something works.

Comment: Hi @Tomalak - You'd be surprised how many times I have been on Wc3 to check out the syntax for XPATH but still find myself in trial an error land. One of the reaons is I only ever seem to find very simple examples given which are not so much in tune with real life situations. I hope this post will help someone else to actually see real code and real solutions. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Don't read the spec, read a tutorial. The easiest analogy is to think of XML as a file system that allows multiple files of the same name in the same directory. (Consequently XPath always selects *all* matching files.) But... since you still seem to have trouble with XML itself, maybe you should go a step back and start *there*, before you concentrate on languages that rely on XML.

Comment: Sound advice, thanks.